# bash configuration files, load configuration from other files

Tags: bash, shell-script

On my computer the user is loaded thru NIS.

In the NIS user honme directory there are configuration files, like `.bashrc`, `.bashprofile` etc.

On some client computers there is also a directory `.config` with configuration files.

I want the bash configuration files, to search for this configuration directories, and if they exist and inside there is a file with the same name to load the configuration from it.

Example:

```
home/user1/.bashrc (NIS home directory)
/slocal/.config/.bashrc
```

So, if `/slocal/.config/.bashrc` exist `home/user1/.bashrc' to loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you just need something like

```
if [ -r /slocal/.config/.bashrc ]; then
  . /slocal/.config/.bashrc
fi
```

inside the `/home/user1/.bashrc` file. The `-r` tests for existence and readability and the `.` then conditionally sources the file.